# Arista adding multiple route-map match interfaces?

Tags: cisco, arista, route-map

on Cisco, I could do the following,

```
route-map abc permit 10 
 match interface Vlan1 Vlan2 Vlan3
 set metric-type type-1
```

But seems on Arista EOS I could only add one match interface, how could I add multiple interfaces match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create multiple entries, and it checks each one until it finds a match, similar to the way an ACL works:

```
route-map abc permit 10 
 match interface Vlan1
 set metric-type type-1
!
route-map abc permit 20 
 match interface Vlan2
 set metric-type type-1
!
route-map abc permit 30 
 match interface Vlan3
 set metric-type type-1
!
```